# Using void pointers as template and function parameters in C#

Tags: c#

Being a bit of a C++ fanatic, i am in desperate need of using void pointers in C#. The task at hand requires me to **not** know the type of a certain variable at compile time. 
So, i thought about preparing a structure with all the info needed to identify the type at runtime. Now, the idea would work in C++, however, C# isn't quite as C++.:wq
   In particular, i need to define a:

```
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, void*>>> mappings;
```

The first problem starts here. .Net isn't letting me define eh `KeyValuePair` as `<string, void*>`. The error i get is:  Error 3 The type 'void*' may not be used as a type argument. 
 The error message is quite straightforward, however, having the possibility of doing this will save me a couple of days of work.
 The second problem is in the same neighborhood. I need to define this function:

```
 public unsafe void addMapping(string name, string internal_name, void* storage)
```

again, not allowed, in this case: Error 2 The type 'void*' may not be used as a type argument
  Is there some way around these issues?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `:wq`... vim user detected :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, `void*` can point to anything.

In C#, every <strike>thing</strike> [*class, structure, enumeration, and delegate*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) derives from `System::Object`, so `object` can refer to any instance.  Just use `KeyValuePair<string, object>`.

Comment: Sorry for the :wq \! old habits die hard i guess.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ironically, not everything derives from object. In particular, pointer types do not; that's why you can't use them as type arguments.

Comment: @Eric: Pedanticism level increased.

Comment: @kvb: Fail.  Pedanticism lost.  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pedanticism

Answer (score 1):

As Ben notes, you probably do not actually need to do this crazy thing. The C# type system already supports a universal "object" reference type. You can use the "is" and "as" operators and the "GetType()" method to do runtime type analysis of any managed object. I suspect you are building a device that is unnecessary.

If you really truly do need to track stuff via void pointers, and you really do need to make a generic map of void pointers, then use System.IntPtr as the type argument. An IntPtr is a pointer-sized integer, and you can convert void* to IntPtr and back again without too much difficulty.

Comment: Even `IntPtr` isn't quite a 100% replacement for `void*`.  In C++, a `void*` could target a member of an instance on the heap.  In C#, some refactoring will be needed (the same lifting as is done when closures capture value type variables, I believe), and then `object` will work to reference the container type.  In C++/CLI, there's an `interior_ptr` type but it is restricted to stack usage and thus can't be stored in a `Dictionary`.  So another case where the maxim holds: **"Any problem in computer science can be solved through the addition of another layer of indirection."**

Comment: I miss my void*'s. It extends C++ power to great lengths. Now, i am about to make a possibly conflictive statement: one could even, for certain situations, simulate dynamic typing.

Comment: @horacv: If your code has `void*`, it's more C than C++.  If you were using C++ features, like template duck-typing, appropriately you could probably avoid the use of `void*` completely.  And C++0x lambdas will make that even easier.